# C: Format specifies type 'char *'

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, format-specifiers

Whenever I run the following code, I get the error message

> "format specifies type `char *` but the argument has type `int`."

The program is supposed to print a n by n square or triangle of a specific character. I'm pretty new to C, and I haven't had much luck troubleshooting this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void print_square(int n, char c) {
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%c", c);
    }
        printf("\n");
}
}

void print_triangle(int n, char c) {
    int count = 1;
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j; j < count; j++) {
            printf("%c", c);
    }
        count = count + 1;
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

int n;
char cmd;
char * c;

do {

    printf("Enter T for a triangle, S for a square, "
           "Q to quit: ");
    scanf("%c", &cmd);
    cmd = toupper(cmd);

    if (cmd == 'S' || cmd == 'T') {
        printf("Enter the size: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("Enter the character: ");
        scanf("%c", *c); // error here

        if (cmd == 'S') {
            print_square(n, *c);
        }

        else {
            print_triangle(n, *c);
        }
    }

} while (cmd != 'T' && cmd != 'S' && cmd != 'Q');

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe there is a difference between `char *` and `char`

Comment: the compiler also outputs some other warnings:  1) unused parameter `argv[]` and unused parameter `argc`.   Suggest change signature of main() to `int main( void )`   2) this line: `scanf("%c", *c);`, the parameters much be address pointer, not contents.  suggest: `scanf("%c", &c);`  also the declaration of `c` is not correct.  it should be: `char c;` not `char *c;`

Comment: applying my prior comment, also means the calls to: `print_square()` and `print_triangle()` should have a second parameter of `c`, not `*c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've pointed already, the error is indeed in

```
  scanf("%c", *c);
```

You need to pass a valid pointer to `char`, why to dereference?

*Note: In your case, you're dereferencing an unitialized pointer, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), anyway.*

To have a better approach (you dont really need `c` to be a pointer there) do something like

```
  char c;
  scanf(" %c", &c);  //the leading space consumes the newline in input bufer
```

and you should be good to go.

Accordingly, you need to pass `c` instead of `*c`, as required in other function calls.

Comment: @TyCharm please note the space in front of the `%c` format specifier. This consumes newline and other whitespace left in input buffer from previous inputs.

Comment: @WeatherVane whoo!! I though I missed that. Added a comment to highlight the same. :)

Comment: well almost.  The calls to the sub functions `print_*()` need to have the second parameter be `c` not `*`c` and the declaration: `char *c;` needs to be changed to `char c`.